# Ansible remove last character from string if its a number

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list like the following

```yaml
fruit: [ 'apple','orange2','grape3apple1']
```

I want an output like the following and want this to be stored in another var for further use

```yaml
fruit_out: [ 'apple','orange','grape3apple' ]
```

If the last character is a number, I want the number stripped, if not, I need the string returned as is. I have looked around a bit without much luck getting any usable solution.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about where you're having difficulties? There are several steps to this problem (looping over a list of strings, referring to the last character in a string, dynamically creating a new variable, etc). Which ones are you able to resolve on your own?

Comment: My problem is with isolating the string without the character at the end. I am familiar with looping through or registering the vars. Not so knowledgable with jinja2 filters to perhaps isolate the content that I need

Comment: Given a string variable `somevariable`, `somevariable[-1]` is the last character, and `somevariable[:-1]` is the string not including the last character.

Comment: I am looking for a validation to check if the last character is indeed a number. If there is a number at in the middle it should not count for the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a regex and the filter [`regex_search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ 
        fruits
        | map('regex_search', '^(.*?)[0-9]?$', '\1')
        | map('first')
      }}
  vars:
    fruits:
      - apple
      - orange2
      - grape3apple1
```

This yields the expected:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - apple
  - orange
  - grape3apple
```

The only tricky part in that regex is that you have to make your capturing group lazy, with the help of the lazy quantifier `*?`, otherwise your matched group will spawn over the unwanted number.

Comment: ok: [ld0290]

*****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ld0290] => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x2b37e50f1b90>"
}

Comment: You are on an old, unmaintained, version of Ansible, upgrade! You could also fix this adding a `| list` after both the last map.

Answer (score 3):

Reiterating my comment for context:

Given a string variable `somevariable`, `somevariable[-1]` is the last character, and `somevariable[:-1]` is the string not including the last character. –

> I am looking for a validation to check if the last character is indeed a number. If there is a number at in the middle it should not count for the check

Ansible uses Python, so you can use any Python [string method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) in your Ansible playbooks.  For example, to have a task execute when a value ends with a number, you could write:

```
- debug:
    msg: Your variable ends with a number!
  when: somevariable[-1].isdigit()
```

You could perform the same check using a regular expression filter:

```
- debug:
    msg: Your variable ends with a number!
  when: somevariable is search('[0-9]$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter [*regex_replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions). For example, put the declarations below as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

```yaml
fruit: [apple, orange2, grape3apple1]
fruit_regex: '^(.+?)\d*$'
fruit_replace: '\1'
fruit_out: "{{ fruit|map('regex_replace', fruit_regex, fruit_replace)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
fruit_out:
  - apple
  - orange
  - grape3apple
```

Explanation of the [*regex*](https://pythex.org/)

```
^ ....... matches the beginning of a string
(.+?) ... creates a capture group
 .    ... matches any character
  +?  ... 1 or more (append ? for non-greedy)  
\d*   ... digit, 0 or more
$ ....... matches the end of a string
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    fruit: [apple, orange2, grape3apple1]
    fruit_regex: '^(.+?)\d*$'
    fruit_replace: '\1'
    fruit_out: "{{ fruit|map('regex_replace', fruit_regex, fruit_replace)|list }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: fruit_out
```